# Do I have to break the tabs

Tags: electrical

What happens if I don't break the tab to make it only half hot. Can I leave it so both sockets are hot. Is that safe.?

Comment: Your question would be a lot better and likely to get more useful answers if you provide context regarding what you are doing. We're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

The while point of splitting a socket is to control each half separately. For instance, one is always-hot and the other is switched by a light switch.  Both sides of the socket *should* be hot, just maybe not all the time.

If the tab was broken before, and you want both sockets to act the same, then OK.. Don't break the tab, **but only connect one of the wires on that side.**  If it doesn't have the action you want, then use the other wire instead.  Cap off the unused wire by putting a (smaller) wire-nut on it, then taping the nut to the wire so it doesn't come off.  That can be a problem with a single wire on a wire nut.

If the tab was broken off before, and you don't break it off now, then **absolutely do not attach both wires**. This can cause all sorts of problems, such as cause switches to stop working, or even a 208/240V dead short.

Answer (score 1):

### Same leg of the service, and same branch circuit

In this case, the whole receptacle would always be hot. Potential for a parallel neutral.

### Same leg of the service, different branch circuits

The whole receptacle would always be hot. Depending on how the neutral was wired, you'd have the potential to overload the neutral, or you'd have a parallel neutral.

### Opposite legs of the service

This would create a 240 volt short-circuit.